# Debian Wine Japanese script problem

Tags: debian, wine

So I'm running Debian Linux 9.2 (stable) and trying to install Japanese video games in Wine. It works fine for the most part, however I cannot get both Japanese characters and half-width alphanumeric characters to display correctly at the same time. If I just launch the application in Wine normally with my locale set to en_US.UTF-8 the Japanese text is completely garbled (as expected). But if I launch the application in Wine prefixing the command with LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8 the Japanese text gets displayed correctly but all the half-width alphanumeric characters are now shown as boxes.

Here are two pictures to clarify what I mean:

LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V3Gtr.png

LC_ALL=ja_JP.UTF-8: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aV1Z3.png

So my question is, how can I get all the text to display correctly in Wine? I'm using Wine 1.8.7-2 from the Debian repositories, however I also tried this with a more recent Wine version from WineHQ with the same results.

Edit: IIRC this worked correctly when I was using Linux Mint for a short while, so is there maybe some package I'm missing or something?

I have no problems with Japanese text outside of Wine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by installing winetricks allfonts.